# Replacing an array values in script with input values of view in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc, ienumerable

I have this code for  view(model's value):

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <input name="DepID" type="text" value="@item.DepID" id="id">
  <input name="DepName" type="text"  value="@item.DepName" id="depname">
  <input name="DepID_Parent" type="text"  value="@item.DepID_Parent" 
id="parent">
}
```

on the other hand, I have an array like below in my script:

```
var testData = [
 { id: 1, name: 'my organization', parent: 0 },
 { id: 2, name: 'ceo office', parent: 1 },
 { id: 3, name: 'division 1', parent: 1 },
 { id: 4, name: 'division 2', parent: 1 },
 { id: 6, name: 'division 3', parent: 1 },
 { id: 7, name: 'division 4', parent: 1 },
 { id: 8, name: 'division 5', parent: 1 },
 { id: 5, name: 'sub division', parent: 3 },
];
```

I want  to replace the value off all inputs to testData array, and use them in my script.

So,I change the definition of testData with this code for script:

```
var testData = $('#id,#depname,#parent').map(function () {
            return testData.value;
        }).get();
```

But when I replace testData with this code, the values aren't returned.

What changes must be done?

Comment: Same `Id` in the loop will generate more than one item with same Id which is invalid HTML. Fix that first

Comment: Are you trying to generate an array like what you have in testData, by reading the input values ?

Comment: @Shyju I changed  the  `id="id"`  to `id="baseid"` ,then I changed  `#id` to `#baseid` in script. but the results were't changed.

Comment: I am still not understanding what is your expected behavior! Can you answer my previous comment ?

Comment: @Shyju  Yes. I want to replace values for id, name and parent in testdata with values of inputs. for instance id:(#baseid).val. Is it obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some issues. You are setting a static `id` attribute value to your input elements inside a loop. So when razor executes your code, it will generate markup for more than one input with the same `id` attribute value. That is invalid HTML! element Id's should be unique inside a document

From the comments you added to the question, you want to create a javascript array similar to what you have in `testData` variable, by reading the input values from your DOM. I suggest you wrap the inputs for each item in the collection, inside a wrapper div. You can use a jQuery selector on this wrapper div later to get the items to build your array. Make sure to remove the code which sets the same id attribute value inside the loop

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="item-row">
        <input name="DepID" type="text" value="@item.DepID" />
        <input name="DepName" type="text"  value="@item.DepName" />
        <input name="DepID_Parent" type="text"  value="@item.DepID_Parent" />
    </div>
}
```

Now in your javascript, get all the divs with `item-row` class, and get the inputs (using the `name` selector) and build the object with the 3 properties.

This should work

```
var testData = $("div.item-row").map(function () {
    var t = $(this);

    return {
        id: t.find("[name='DepID']").val(),
        name: t.find("[name='DepName']").val(),
        parent: t.find("[name='DepID_Parent']").val()
    };
}).get();
//testData is an array of js objects with 3 properties
console.log(testData);
```

Comment: `id` and `parent` are int, this code return srting type for them. How can I change it to `int`?

Comment: `val()` returns a string. Why do you need it as int ? If you are sending that to server and using `int` as the type, the parsing will automatically happen for you (during model binding). If you need the numeric type in javascript, use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` as needed.